# Data not getting when i fire two parallel http request

Tags: angular, typescript, fork-join

In angular 2 i am using multiple services but i am not able to get data from first Api at subscribe function of second api so please suggest me the suitable answer.

Comment: Please supply more details, including code if necessary, which it probably will be. As it is, this question is most likely unanswerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as 2 async HTTP requests. When the first request fires, before getting a response it fires the second.

In Angular it happens in the same way. To avoid this situation angular introduced ForkJoin:

[image]

Fork-join is given to create multiple HTTP requests at the same time and after getting a response from all of them it calls a final subscribe method.

```
    Observable.forkJoin(

    this.http.post(glob.BASE_API_URL_HOTEL + "hotel/getRoomType?hotelCode=" + this.hotel,{}).map(res => res.json()),

    this.http.get(glob.BASE_API_URL_HOTEL + "hotel/getBedType").map(res => res.json())

    ).subscribe((data)=>{



    this.roomType = data[0].data;
    this.getBedType = data[1].data;
}
```

Here, two requests are initiated simultaneously and in the subscribe callback you will get an array of all responses.